# How to create a package.json script that runs a file from node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I have installed the `react-clear-cache` package and in the docs it says that I need to add a new script to my `package.json`.

This is my package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "prebuild": "npm run generate-build-meta",
    "generate-build-meta": "./node_modules/react-clear-cache/bin/cli.js"
  },
```

According to the docs I need to run `npm run generate-build-meta` but everytime I try, node tells me that it wasnt able to find `"./node_modules/react-clear-cache/bin/cli.js"`

What I should do to correctly run this `cli.js`?

By the way, I have the `react-clear-cache` in my node_modules and I can see the `cli.js`

This is the message I receive:
[image]

It is pretty much saying that '.' is not recognized as an internal command.

Comment: do you see that package in your node_modules directory?

Comment: Yes, I do @SamPetering

Comment: What is the exact error message? Please [edit] your question to include it exactly word for word rather than summarizing it. Better yet, google the error message. There's a good chance that someone else has already posted somewhere about that exact error.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm posting here exactly bc I did not found an answer to my question.

Comment: try replacing the script with `npm run react-clear-cache` and running it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "prebuild": "npm run generate-build-meta",
    "generate-build-meta": "react-clear-cache"
  },
```

Accessing `node_modules` binaries by path is unnecessary in `package.json` scripts. Within the `package.json`, you can proceed as though `node_modules/**/bin/` is in your `$PATH`.

Comment: it says that 'react-clear-cache' is not recognized as an internal command

Comment: If I try reproducing this with a minimal `package.json`, I get the same error. This package may be doing things in a non-standard way. Attempting to run the file directly (`npx react-clear-cache`) gets me a similar error to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/noahjohn9259/react-clear-cache/issues/31).

Comment: This is odd. I will try to create a git issue in this repo. Thanks anyway @backtick

I will give you the correct answer since you had the effort to run it in your machine, thanks man.